# Openstack heat template : float number as an input parameter

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I want to provide a floating point number as an input parameter. When I select the parameter type to be a "number", providing a float number results in an error, stating : "enter a whole number". Has anyone tried it out ?
The openstack heat template documentation clearly states that, with a parameter type number, one can enter an integer or a float number. Not sure why it isn't working.
I'm using openstack Newton, and here is a sample template which isn't working according to expectations :

```
heat_template_version: 2016-10-14
description: test template
parameters:
  number:
    type: number
    label: a number
    description: a number
    default: 0.1
    constraints:
        - range: { min: 0.0, max: 100.0 }
resources:
  random:
    type: OS::Heat::RandomString
    properties:
      length: 10
```

Note : the sole purpose of the above template is to test floating point number as input.

Thanks in advance for help.

[I get the following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuP6U.jpg)

Comment: "openstack orchestration template validate" seems to be returning success for the code snippet you mentioned.
What is the exception are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I get the following error when I launch the instance from the above template : Please enter a valid value, two nearest valid value are 0 and 1.